# In matplotlib, how to draw multiple labelled lines with all labels in front of all lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib

http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/line_with_text.html shows how lines with line labels can be plotted. 
The label stays on the right position even if the user zooms in or out in the interactive window.

However, if I draw several such lines that overlap, the text label from one line might be behind another line.

Can I put the all line labels in front of all lines? How can this be achieved.

Using `self.text = mtext.Text(0, 0, '', zorder=100)` in the constructor of MyLine does not help.

`line.text.set_zorder(10000)` does not help either.

## Minimal example

Taken and modified from http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/line_with_text.html (matplotlib 1.5.1 - [License](http://matplotlib.org/users/license.html?highlight=license#license-agreement-for-matplotlib-version) )

I did not copy the MyLine class to the code below. It is at the above url.

```py
# The code below may be 
# Copyright (c) 2012-2013 Matplotlib Development Team; All Rights Reserved
# used under the Matplotlib license and modified
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as lines
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
import matplotlib.text as mtext
#Insert MyLine class from 
#http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/line_with_text.html here.

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for _ in range(20):
  x, y = np.random.rand(2, 5)
  line = MyLine(x, y, mfc='red', ms=12, label='line label')
  line.text.set_color('red')
  line.text.set_fontsize(16)
  ax.add_line(line)

plt.show()
```

[image: Multiple labelled lines drawn with matplotlib: The labels of some lines are behind other lines]

In the picture, some lines are in front of some labels.
How can I draw multiple lines with a label for each line in a way that all labels are z-order wise in front of all lines?